# "К главе" — как выговаривать?

Tags: орфоэпия, предлоги

Ехал в метро и увидел у девушки рядом в книге: *что-то* (допустим, примечания) *к главе N.* И вот я задумался: с одной стороны, "к**о** главе" в наше время вроде не говорят, а с другой — ***непонятно, как правильно выговаривать это [кг].*** Иначе как проглотить К и произнести лишь Г у меня не получается.

Comment: К перед Гозвончается и произносится удвоенный ГГ. Наверное.

Comment: Я так и думал, но как произнести именно ***удвоенный**,* плохо понимаю.

Comment: Очень просто. Сначала произнесите: замечание главе (без удвоения Г). Но мы же "не делаем главе никаких замечаний". Постарайтесь исключить такое понимание,  сравнив два варианта произношения.

Comment: Кажется, я понял, как должно звучать. :)